# Как понимать работу jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, байткод

Я начал интересоваться, как работает виртуальная машина Java.

На данный момент я знаю, что исходный код java компилятором преобразуется в байткод. Соответственно этот байткод — это и есть инструкции для виртуального процессора виртуальной машины. Сама jvm зависит от платформы, на которой она используется.

Но вот теперь вопрос, раз сама JVM — платформа, имеющая свой ненастоящий процессор который понимает инструкции (байткод), то где в этой цепочке программа преобразуется в машинный код, который уже будет исполнять реальный процессор компьютера? JVM же когда-то должна сгенерировать машинной код, который зависит от какой либо операционной системы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### При *компиляции* JVM (не работе!) под этот процессор и ОС.

Код, который обходит JVM-байткод и выполняет соответствующие системные команды без предварительной их компиляции это **код самой JVM** на каком-то языке, который компилируется соответствующим компилятором напрямую в машинный код (скажем, JVM проекта OpenJDK написана на C++).

Можно условно представить, что для каждого вида команды в JVM-байткоде есть фрагментик машинного кода в самой JVM, выполнение которого даёт требуемый этой командой эффект.

---

Но это если не учитывать JIT. Который целые последовательности команд (а не отдельные команды) преобразует в соответствующий машинный код, но уже в процессе *работы*. Но там-то понятно, откуда машинный код берётся.

Comment: Тоесть правильно ли я понял что сначала, возьмём к примеру jvm написана на с++ и это означает что перед запуском jvm будет компилироваться, и во время компиляции jvm будет синтерпритирован байткод, после чего завершится компиляция jvm и программа будет запущена?  Я могу сказать полную глупость, потому что до конца ещё не могу разобраться, поэтому если что извините))

Comment: @Nikita да, сказали :) Но это ничего. Смотрите. Как правило, уже скомпилированная заранее JVM помещается в установочный пакет и распространяется пользователям. На этом этапе байткод участвует лишь как обобщённые определения, в отрыве от конкретных программ на байткоде. Пользователь скачает JVM, установит и запустит ею что-то. А уже после запуска те участки, что JVM нужно интерпретировать (без учёта компиляции), она **обходит по одной команде, выполняя для каждой соответствующий кусок машинного кода из себя**.

Comment: Оо до меня дошло теперь!  Большое спасибо,  за то что разжевали мне все)) теперь буду иметь в виду

Comment: А вот ещё вопрос, который меня тоже долго мучает, в виртуальной машине есть какой то виртуальный процессор, понимающий байт код или же это все лишь условно и так говорят просто чтобы создать впечатление как будто это действительно виртуальный компьютер, на самом деле не процессор, а лишь интерпритатор который разбирает и преобразует  байткод ведь так? ))

Comment: Можно условно представить, что для каждого вида команды в JVM-байткоде есть фрагментик машинного кода в самой JVM, выполнение которого даёт требуемый этой командой эффект. - Кстати говоря это очень интересная мысль и без неё так и не было бы понятно откуда что берётся, и эту информацию нигде в статьях я не находил))

Comment: Интерпретатор и есть то, что вы называете "виртуальным процессором". Равно как процессор-железяка есть аппаратный интерпретатор своего машинного кода. Мне лично было бы странно писать такую информацию в статье, т. к. это как раз наивный (очевидный) способ реализовать любой  интерпретатор команд: свич по коду команды и кусок кода для каждого значения.

Comment: Здорово!  Но для новичка вроде меня это очень полезная информация, ещё раз спасибо, что уделили время и все подробно и хорошо объяснили!